# What is the source of the following sloka?

Tags: identification-request, shloka

The following lines I got in Ahnik-Krittya by Shyamacharan Kaviratna Vidyavaridhi (that supports the members of HisE  offering bounty!:))

> sreyo'rthino hi purushAh paratushi-hetoh kashtarjitani api dhanani parityajanti. For getting the optimum, individuals sacrifice even their hard-earned wealth.

What is the source of this sloka ?

Comment: @Rickross pl correct:)